# File does not exist (ncjoes/office-converter, laravel)

Tags: laravel

i was using ncjoes/office-converter, trying to upload .docx and convert it to .pdf, but it occurred error when it converts to .pdf

the error shows **NcJoes\OfficeConverter\OfficeConverterException
File does not exist --test.docx**

view

```
<form action="/notes" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
@method('POST')
<div>
<label for="title">title：</label>
<input id="title" name="title">
</div>
<div>
<label for="topdf">upload：</label>
<input type="file" id="topdf" name="topdf">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-primary">add</button>
</form>
```

controller

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'topdf' => 'required|mimes:docx',
        'title'=>'required'
    ]);
    $Name = str_replace(" ","",$request->input('title'));
    $FileName = $Name . '.' . $request->topdf->extension();
    $request->topdf->move(public_path('pdf'), $FileName);
    $converter = new OfficeConverter($FileName);
    //$fin=$converter->convertTo('output-file.pdf');
    //$fin->move(public_path('pdf'), $FileName);

}
```

i think `$converter = new OfficeConverter($FileName);` was wrong, but idk how to fix ;;

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel v8.20.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First upload the file this way:

```
$file = $request->file('topdf')->store('pdf');
$path = Storage::path($file);
```

And then, try to access the file and convert via the $path variable:

```
$converter = new OfficeConverter($path);
```

Comment: it had the same error, do i need to edit filesystems, or something else?

Comment: yes indeed. Do you have this "pdf" folder in your /storage/app directory?

Comment: Please once dd($path) and see what it returns.

Comment: directory was existing, and dd($path) returns "pdf/dPb3WD4xK2w0DFR4oLg6fIBaikBzRfv8UiKskdx7.docx", this file has same name in /storage/app/pdf

Comment: Have a look at the answer now. I have edited it.

Comment: thanks!! now it can read .docx file!!
but it have other error instead lol, anyway, thanks for help!

Comment: I would love to help. Please share the error

Comment: it's was some problem about NcJoes\OfficeConverter, i fixed it, and now work well, thank you !